# Reg Expression, Handling a URL exclusions

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am trying to write a regexp to use with Crazyegg that will allow me to only gather data from my product pages.

My site structure is:

- category page: `www.sitename.com/categoryname/sub-categoryname`
- product page: `www.sitename.com/productname/`

My regex so far is:

```
^https?://([A-Za-z0-9.-]*\.)?sitename\.com/[A-Za-z0-9.-]*(/|/\?|)$
```

This allows everything that isnt at the sub category level (2nd level folder?)

the issue is that this allow top level categories so I need to exclude these by their name for example:

```
^https?://([A-Za-z0-9.-]*\.)?sitename\.com/(?!\babout\b|\bcheckout\b)(/|/\?|)$
```

Could you please help me get the exclusion correct? ive also tried doing using `[^\babout\b|\bcheckout\b]`

Comment: `(/|/\?|)$` should ideally return an error because of the last `|`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice as most google analytics accepted it as being empty. Any idea on the question its self though? how to exclude specific pages.

Comment: Can you give a few examples of text that should match and a few examples of text that should *not* match?

Answer (score 0):

if you only want product pages, the regex for capture product pages is:
".*productname"

For capture category pages: ".*categoryname/sub-categoryname"

I hope help you. If you have more questions, ask me!